# How to underline the scope of parentheses my cursor in, in emacs?

Tags: emacs, underline

How can I do this:

Let | be the current cursor position, "bold" as "underlined"

when:        (this | is the (example text))

emacs will: **(this | is the (example text))**

when:   (this is the (example | text))

emacs will: (this is the **(example | text)**)

thanks you guys, [vim version is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12161508/is-it-possible-to-have-vim-underline-the-scope-of-parentheses-my-cursor-is-curre)

Comment: it will be better if i can add to .emacs

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few similarly-named options:

- [hl-sexp.el](http://edward.oconnor.cx/elisp/hl-sexp.el)
- [highlight-sexp.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HighlightSexp)
- [highlight-sexps.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HighlightSexps)

I use the first one, but I've not tried the others.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. elisp is elisp; it makes little difference which file it is in.

Comment: I mean that i want just put a couple of lines in .emacs to do that,
don't want to add new .el files, cause it's hard to maintain lots files, compared with a single .emacs
thanks again, your answer working WELL now ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Command `hlt-highlight-enclosing-list` does what you are asking.  Repeating it highlights bigger enclosing lists.  The command is in library [`highlight.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/highlight.el).  Or you can just give a prefix arg to highlight outward from point that many levels of parentheses.

You can specify any face you want, on the fly.  It is used for highlighting until you choose another face.
Command `hlt-unhighlight-region` undoes the highlighting in the region or the whole buffer.

See [Highlight Library](http://www.emacswiki.org/HighlightLibrary).